# What does this Openid error mean: Error attempting to use stored discovery information

Tags: python, openid, django-openid-auth

I'm attempting to setup an app using django-openid and openid.
I'm getting the following errors and I can't figure out what is causing them.

```
[Fri Jan 29 13:29:20 2010] [error] Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud with assocication XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
[Fri Jan 29 13:29:26 2010] [error] Error attempting to use stored discovery information: <openid.consumer.consumer.TypeURIMismatch: Required type http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon not found in ['http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server', 'http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0'] for endpoint <openid.consumer.discover.OpenIDServiceEndpoint server_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud' claimed_id=None local_id=None canonicalID=None used_yadis=True >>  
[Fri Jan 29 13:29:26 2010] [error] Attempting discovery to verify endpoint  
[Fri Jan 29 13:29:26 2010] [error] Performing discovery on https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=PrHw_N5_3j1HM  
[Fri Jan 29 13:29:26 2010] [error] Received id_res response from https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud using association XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

It looks like Python can't use the information that is being retrieved from Google.
Is this error because of the data coming from Google or is it a problem with openid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.  That's actually not a fatal error; I get the same thing when using the python-openid consumer example against google's OP Identifier (the /accounts/o8/id one that generates the funny directed identifiers), but it successfully logs in.

That probably causes some log spam if you have a "log in with google" button and the library maybe could be smartenified to not try to used the stored discovery information when it was for an OP Identifier, but if you're not able to log in at all, something else is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the URL given is the server's URL, instead of the Claimed Identifier.  It's a genuine error for the pathway that generates it, because the URL can't be used as an identifier, but it gets caught internally and used to request a true identifier from the server, so it's safe to ignore the log messages.  Nevertheless, [a bug report](https://github.com/openid/python-openid/issues/23) has been submitted to the python-openid project on GitHub, with a proposed fix.